# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CSharp' when logged in with user which is not a member of administrator group

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, permissions

I have created a website which compiles successfully when I log-in using **administrator** but when I log-in using any other user, following error occurs.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. Either a required impersonation level was not provided,
>   or the provided impersonation level is invalid. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070542)

The **administrator** user is member of

- Acronis Remote Users
- Administrators
- Remote Desktop Users

while the other user is member of

- Acronis Remote users
- Administrators *
- IIS_IUSRS
- Remote Desktop Users
- SQLServerMSSQLUser$vm-tmp-abcd-1$MSSQLSERER
- Users

I am using
Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise with 64-bit Operating System

- Initially the other user didn't belong to **administrators** group. I added the **administrators** role to it but still I am getting the same error.

NOTE: It compiles the website successfully if I choose VS2010 to **run as administrator**.

Comment: Um, you said in the title that you cant load the assembly except when user is part of the administrators group - but the user you listed, you then listed as an administator...

Comment: @BugFinder, I have edited the question to clarify the issue raised by you.

Comment: This does need to be loaded as FullTrust is this the problem rather than the user?

Comment: @@Mike Miller, you are correct that the problem is FullTrust. I have located Microsoft.CSharp dll (in GAC_MSIL) and shared it to everyone but invain.

Comment: do you use <identity impersonate="true"...> in web.config file? if yes then give right to that user and it may fix it

Answer (score 17):

This one solved my problem.

1. Right click on Visual studio (whichever version you use)
2. Properties
3. Select compatibility tab
4. Fill the checkbox which says "Run this program as administrator"
5. Open the project from the file location
6. Run the application

Comment: You should be logged in as administrator.

Comment: Yippy Yippy Yo. Thanks @CoffeeSipper . Save a lot of time.

Comment: Does not work for latest version of windows. Compatibility settings have been moved. Please modify answer, meanwhile i've posted an answer here for windows 10 users.

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised when I can't find options always run as administrator for file of vs 2017 pro (devenv.exe). It was resolved and set only with troubleshoot compatibility option.

Solution for the latest window versions:

```
  - Find  "devenv.exe" file
  - Right mouse click and selects "troubleshoot compatibility" option
  - Troubleshoot program option
  - Checks "The program requires additional permissions"
  - Next
  - Test the program
  - Next 
  - Yes,save these settings for this program
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does not work in the latest version of windows. My Windows 10 operating system with VS 2017 did not have a "Compatibility Tab" in the properties window - it appears they have now moved this option.

**For windows 10 users, follow the below steps:**

Firstly, you need to be logged in as an administrator for the computer you're using.

1. Right click Visual Studio (whichever version).
2. Click "properties" - and a properties window will open.
3. Click on the "Shortcut" tab.
4. Click on "Advanced" box - at the bottom right.
5. Check the "Run as Administrator" box, and click OK.
6. Click "Apply" and then "OK" on the Visual Studio Properties window.

**For previous versions, please follow the following steps**

1. Right click Visual Studio (whichever version).
2. Click "properties" - and a properties window will open.
3. Click on the "Compatibility" tab.
4. Check the "Run as Administrator" box.
5. Click "Apply" and then "OK" on the Visual Studio Properties window.

**Your project should now open up as administrator going forwards, and common access issues to the Assembly will be resolved.**