# Unhandled Excecution error while debugging project in asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am having windows 8.1 and I upgrade it 2 days a go. After upgrading, When I open my visual studio and debug any of my project so I got the error that you can see in last that I have provided. I had also re-installed visual studio 13 but still I am getting this error. Any help will be highly appreciated.

> Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CSharp,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. Either a required impersonation level was not
>   provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80070542)

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio as an administrator?

Comment: Chek it out: Here: 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078404/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-csharp-when-logged-in-with-user-whic

Hope it will help you